# Chrome Weird Shortcut

Tags: google-chrome

I recently ran the ubuntu updater on my computer, and it seems like it messed up my google chrome installation. Every time I open Google chrome, on the menu bar, instead of showing up as the normal chrome icon, it shows a slightly blurrier version, and when I put my mouse over it, it says "Digital Ocean Control Panel", which was one of the tabs when the updater ran.

What can I do to get rid of this? I tried uninstalling chrome, I tried purging chrome, and I also tried deleting `~/.config/google-chrome`, but still when I reopen chrome, it shows up on the menu bar as Digital ocean, instead of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

This tutorial did the trick! http://kb.openstudioproject.com/content/fix-double-google-chrome-icon-docky-and-plank

Quote:

After the update to Chrome 35 and again with the update to 36 I discovered the launcher in docky and plank wasn't matching the chrome window correctly anymore. So it would show the launcher with a nice icon and then the actually launched app with a very low quality icon. Luckily, it's a simple fix... so let's get started. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

You'll find 3 entries in this file, [Desktop Entry], [NewWindow Shortcut Group] and [NewIncognito Shortcut Group]. Make sure that under each group there's the following line, it doesn't matter where in the group it is.

```
StartupWMClass=Google-chrome-stable
```

For convenience, here is the modified chrome.desktop file for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr. Just replace it with the one you have in /usr/share/applications/.